# HyperV Server Recommendations

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware, hypervisor

Looking to implement HyperV on 2008 R2... We currently use an HP DL380, but we are looking to expand a bit and were thinking maybe a blade solution was the answer... Or an HP DL370 G6... Or the Intel Modular MFSYS25...

We currently host about 12 VM's on dual-quad-core 16GB server, but we are looking to eventually setup failover VM's for our production web application and Exchange.

What is considered the best hardware for this type of Hyper-V implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I user HP BL460c G6's all over the place and they're great; fast, easy to deal with etc - couldn't recommend them higher if you want blades. The 370 would be a bit of a backwards step from a 380 really, love the new 380 G6's, especially when you add the second PCIe riser and disk cage (6 PCI slots, 4 NICs and 16 disks in 2U!).

I don't think you could go wrong with any of this kit but if you're looking for more power I'd wait a month or so for the new Magny-Cours chips from AMD to pop up in the 385/585/795's, well worth the wait or if you can wait a little longer still Intel's Xeon 75xx series chips are REALLY worth holding out for in the 580/790/990 G7s.

Comment: Thanks for the info... We did spec out the BL460c with an enclosure, but as expected it was a bit pricey... However, if that is the way to go...

Also, the DL370 G6 is actually a continuation of the ML370 G5 - a powerhouse and step UP from the 380 :)

Comment: @Chopper3 - Question for you: "especially when you add the second PCIe riser and disk cage"

Is the drive cage an external unit, or does it install in the rear of the enclosure?

Comment: Hi you, it's an internal option at the front of the unit, just alongside the existing 8-disk cage and replacing the dvd drive, that way you can have 8TB (raw) inside the 2U server itself. The cage costs about $300 or so extra and the riser is about $75 and gives you extra PCIe slots! Let me know if you need help pulling together a detailed kit-list ok. Oh and I have a bit of a beef with the 370, it's twice the size of the 380 but not twice as powerful, I tend to be a bit of a space/power-nazi, hence my love of blades, someone once told me I buy 1.8% of all the blades HP make :)